# waiting for initial communication packet error 0 while connecting to mysql database server

Tags: mysql, linux, mysql-connector

I am using `mysql` server 5.1.51 on `linux` machine

Application was working fine from last **32 days** but yesterday onward number of client are not able to connect to the database using application and getting below error

```
-2147467259 [MySQL] [ODBC 5.1 Driver] Lost Connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet',system error: 0
```

Please suggest what are possible causes for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding below mentioned database parameter into my.ini solved my problem 
skip-name-resolve

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
skip-locking
skip-name-resolve
```

This parameter skips host name resolving during establishment of application's connection with mysql database server